# Get 100% accuracy score on Decision tree model

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I got 100% accuracy on my decision tree using decision tree algorithm but only got 75% accuracy on random forest

Is there something wrong with my model or is decision tree best suited for the dataset provide?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.3, random_state= 30)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier = classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
print(cm)
```

Comment: Decision trees does overfitting whereas random forest wont

Answer (score 0):

At First it may look like your model is overfitted but it is not the case as you have put the test set aside.

The reason is **Data Leak**. Random Forest, randomly exludes some features for every tree. Now suppose you have the labels as one of the features: in some trees the label got excluded and the accuracy is reduced while in the Decission three the label is always among the featurs and predict the result perfectly.

How can you find if it is the case?
use the visualization for the Decision three and if my guess is true you will find that there a few number of decision nodes. You can also visualize the correlation between label and every feature and check out if there is any perfevt correlation or not.